# How to get non-flagged users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This gets me all users who are flagged:

```
User.joins(:flags)
```

How would I do the opposite of above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
User.find(:all,
          :joins => 'LEFT JOIN flags ON users.flag_id=flags.id',
          :group => 'users.id',
          :having => 'flags.id IS NULL')
```

Comment: This is what I ended up with in Rails 3: User.joins('LEFT JOIN flags ON users.id = flags.flaggable_id AND flags.flaggable_type = "User"').where('flags.id IS NULL')